# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-us-west-1b.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy a file from my aws ec2 instance to S3 bucket folder, but i am getting error

Here is the command sample
**aws s3 cp /home/abc/icon.jpg s3://mybucket/myfolder**

This the error i am getting

**upload failed: ./icon.jpg to s3://mybucket/myfolder/icon.jpg HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-us-west-1b.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /mybucket/myfolder/icon.jpg (Caused by : [Errno -2] Name or service not known)**

I have already configured the config file for aws cli command line

Please suggest the solution to this problem

Answer (score 5):

You aren't using a valid endpoint.

`s3-us-west-1b.amazonaws.com` isn't valid.

S3 endpoints are at the regional level, not the availability zone level.

You're probably looking for `s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: Hi Michael, i tried your solution but it did not work. I am getting this error now `upload failed: ./icon.jpg to s3://mybucket/myfolder/icon.jpg A client error (PermanentRedirect) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`  Please advise

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have to use just **region** which you can see from aws console url there you can find region in url just copy it and use which is your region

**Availability Zone** is different which use have used earlier

**Availability zone** is followed by region along with 
**region a,
region b**

[availability zone status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAkMe.png)

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be that proxy might not have been set in your instance service role. Configure the `env` to point to your proxy servers via `HTTP_PROXY` / `HTTPS_PROXY` (Since the above error displays 443, it should be `HTTPS_PROXY`).