# Uploading to S3 from Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a handle on Docker.  I've got a very basic container setup that runs a simple python script to:

1. Query a database
2. Write a CSV file of the query results
3. Upload the CSV to S3 ([using the tinys3 package](https://github.com/smore-inc/tinys3)).

When I run the script from my host, everything works as intended: the query fires, csv is created and uploaded perfectly.  But when I run it from within my Docker container, tinys3 fails with the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-s3-bucket', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4f17cf7790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Everything prior to that works (query and CSV creation).  [This answer suggests that there's an incorrect endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487444/httpsconnectionpoolhost-s3-us-west-1b-amazonaws-com-port-443-max-retries-e).  But that doesn't seem correct, since running the script from my host does not result in an error.

So my question is: am I missing something obvious?  Is this an issue with the tinys3 module?  Do I need to set something up in my container to allow it to "call out"?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've..."solved" it. There's a slight discrepancy with the naming of the bucket/file name. I can upload '/subbucket/file.csv' as a file, but cannot upload 'file.csv' to 'bucket/subbucket' (even though the latter works on my host).

Comment: How did you solve this problem? My requests are timing out with no error messages

Comment: It was a key error.  So rather than setting the bucket as 'bucket/stuff/test/'' and the file I wanted as 'file.py'  I had to set the bucket to 'bucket' and file name to '/stuff/test/file.py'.  Bizarrely, the former worked locally, but not on my server.  Weird problem, not sure if yours is similar.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can also use [minio-py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py) client library for the same.

Please find example code for [fput_object.py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/examples/fput_object.py)

```
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import ResponseError

client = Minio('s3.amazonaws.com',
               access_key='YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
               secret_key='YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY')
# Put on object 'my-objectname-csv' with contents from
# 'my-filepath.csv' as 'application/csv'.
try:
    client.fput_object('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname-csv',
                       'my-filepath.csv', content_type='application/csv')
except ResponseError as err:
    print(err)
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work with [Minio](https://www.minio.io)